# issue with routing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing this routing issue where once the user hits /home ,it gets redirected to another route /home/render and things are fine .
However ,if one hits home/live ,I don't see that it renders Component1 which is desired .
Here is the link to the codesandbox .
[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2vl54zvwo)

Here is my main Component index.js

```
import App from "./Components/App";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={App} />
            <Route path="/home/render" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Page</div>;
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

and this is my App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log("match.url", match.url);
    console.log("match.path", match.path);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect from={match.url} exact to={match.url + "/render"} />;
          <Route
            path={match.path + "/live"}
            render={routeProps => (
              <Component1
                matchBaseUrl={match.url}
                {...routeProps}
                matchId={100}
              />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I didn't put component.js because that's just a simple component I am rendering on screen when we hit home/live .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Component1` is never rendered because you set the `exact` prop to `true` on the `/home` route, which will make it so it only matches if the path is `/home` and nothing more.

You can remove the `exact` prop and move the route below the `/home/render` route so that takes precedence and it wlll work as expected.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
  <Route path="/home/render" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/home" component={App} />
</Switch>
```